# Enumerated entries in Table of Abbreviations

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, nomenclature, nomencl

I use the `nomencl`-package to create a `Table of Abbreviations`. (Yes, I'm aware of the `glossary`-package, but the template is quite difficult to adapt to it.)

I'd like to have numbered entries in the way:

> 1.1 WYSISWYG What You See Is What You Get .... 'page number'

where the number of the listing and/or the page number is linked with `hyperref` to the abbreviation refered to.

As I have not quite a clue on how to code this, I read the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/nomencl/nomencl.pdf) for pointers. Section 5.5 mentions the Kopka style, which I'd like to expand to what is wanted above.

What would be a quik'n'derty and what would be a smart way to do this?

**EDIT:** MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

%taken from nomencl-manual (ver. 2005)
\def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3{%
 \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}%
  \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
   {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa@[{\nom@verb\@tempa}]%
   |nompageref{\begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}}}%
   {\thepage}}%
\endgroup
\@esphack}{}

\def\nompageref#1#2{%
    \if@printpageref\pagedeclaration{#2}\else\null\fi
    \linebreak#1\nomentryend\endgroup}

\def\pagedeclaration#1{\dotfill\nobreakspace#1}
\def\nomentryend{.}
\def\nomlabel#1{\textbf{#1}\hfil}
%end stolen code 

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature

\section{Some title}

some text is written here. Oh, see! An abbreviation comes along.

Hello, dear abbreviation! How goeth thee?

IGW!\nomenclature{IGW}{It goeth well!}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT2:** Compiler throws error:

`temp.nls line 7:
 Paragraph ended before \nompageref was complete.
 temp.tex line 35:
\begin{thenomenclature} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}.\end{document}`

Comment: You know the name of the game: MWE ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done. be advised: the code is taken from manual and is faulty. I do not fully understand it.

Comment: I will look later on. The first version of your code run without problems, but of course, had no numbers

Comment: I have not found a clue for this, I am sorry, I will investigate further